# Drush site-upgrade always gives mysql error: Access Denied

Tags: drush

I am trying to run "sudo drush site-upgrade @alias" however I invariably get the same large HTML output containing the error block:

```
   <p>The site is currently not available due to technical problems. Please try 
        again later. Thank you for your understanding.</p><hr /><p><small>If you are 
        the maintainer of this site, please check your database settings in the 
        <code>settings.php</code> file and ensure that your hosting provider's 
        database server is running. For more help, see the 
        <a href="http://drupal.org/node/258">handbook</a>, or contact your hosting 
        provider.</small></p><p><small>The <em>mysql</em> error was: <em>Access 
        denied for user &#039;root&#039;@&#039;[HOST NAME WAS HERE]&#039; 
        (using password: YES)</em>.</small></p>          </div>
     ...
     ...
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.
```

I am using the root user of my sql database with the proper password but am still getting this access issue.

Strangely enough any other drush command fails to execute and instead spits back this error. Even "drush help". Drush is working fine in other Drupal site directories on the server